# Tunisia quarantine requirements for citizens

Tags: tunisian-citizens, tunisia

I'm trying to find out the exact quarantine requirements for Tunisian passport holders going to Tunisian from France.

Most websites have requirements for hotel stays but some websites say that passport holders can quarantine for 14 days at home (ex- Air France website).

I am trying to find an official source for some time now but I'm lost. Where should I look?

Comment: Apparently the official communication is done via the Tunisian Health ministry's Facebook page: https://www.facebook.com/santetunisie.rns.tn/photos/pcb.3813292085376534/3813291552043254. There do not seem to be any exceptions for Tunisians, hotel quarantine for a minimum of 7 days is mandatory for everyone. The french embassy in Tunis lists a very limited number of exemptions: https://tn.ambafrance.org/Coronavirus-COVID-19

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.